# Is there an equivalent to <(process list) for variables?

Tags: bash, paste, variable-substitution

I can use `<(some command)` in place of a file, but how can I achieve the equivalent with a variable? I'm using the `paste` command, which expects files as arguments, and want to use the contents of `SOMEVAR` as though it were a file.

```
paste <($SOMEVAR)
```

### Update0

I'd expect something like `<<<(SOMEVAR)` to exist. `<(echo $SOMEVAR)` doesn't work, because echo inserts spaces between arguments, so newlines are lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use `echo` with quotes around the $var as that should preserve the newlines, like this

```
paste <(echo "$SOMEVAR")
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of this!

Answer (score 2):

Use a [*here string*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings) for that. Like this:

```
cmd <<< "$variable"
```

Example:

*file1:*

```
Linux
Unix
Solaris
HPUX
AIX
```

Bash:

```
a=$(<file1)
paste <<< "$a" # Will output the contents of file1
```

Comment: My concern with this is it ties up use of stdin. I want to pass the variable as one of the file arguments.

Comment: @MattJoiner Ok, I missed that requirement. Then go with Soren's answer! That's what you want. A process substitution will get expanded by bash to a file name like `/dev/fd/XY` . Therefore you can even pass multiple of them in a command line and it will not use stdin.